# Singleton in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, caching, singleton, multi-user

If i have a singleton wrapper around a collection in asp.net does it have to be cached or would it's data be persisted across post backs?

Also if another user logs into the app would the app create another instance (of itself) and therefore another instance of the singleton or would it access the same singleton that was created in the first instance?

The actual implementation of the singleton is one of the following:
(Design 1:)

```
using System;

public sealed class Singleton
{
   private static volatile Singleton instance;
   private static object syncRoot = new Object();

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null) 
         {
            lock (syncRoot) 
            {
               if (instance == null) 
                  instance = new Singleton();
            }
         }

         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

or Design 2:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
   private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

   private Singleton(){}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         return instance; 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: How is the singleton implemented?

Comment: Not implemented yet. Probably based on the code:
using System;

public sealed class Singleton
{
   private static volatile Singleton instance;
   private static object syncRoot = new Object();

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null) 
         {
            lock (syncRoot) 
            {
               if (instance == null) 
                  instance = new Singleton();
            }
         }

         return instance;
      }
   }
}

Comment: How about you explain what you are trying to do, and we can suggest ways to do it? Perhaps singleton is wrong or simply not required?

Comment: Is there a reason for not just using the Application object that already is a singleton in ASP.Net that is used for all users?  If you want to separate the data then consider the Session object that may work well in this case.

Comment: Lol, yes i think you nailed the question. I want some data to be publically accessible between all users (hence the singleton). That data will be loaded on app start event. Next i want only some data to exist but only for a particular user.

Comment: I can't use session. I can't use view state. Cache takes too long to access, plus it needs to serialize the data every-time something consumes it.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think Application/Cache requires serialization.  It's just an in memory Hashtable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singleton is pattern that makes sure there is only one instance for all request. Since you have declared it static it exists for lifetime of the application. And the same instance will be returned to any user requesting the object through your property.

Answer (score 4):

A static variable will exist as long as the application is running, until a application restart. It would exist across postbacks and users.

This article shows how to implement a static singleton: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Are there any more requirements on what you are trying to do that would affect the implementation of the singleton?

Comment: No, not really. The only requirement is to store data for all users that would be accessible immediately (in memory), rather than loaded from cache every time it's needed. The other issue though is that I need to do the same for individual user's data, and I have no idea how to achieve that, since a singleton or a static variable persists across all users/sessions. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: For the per-user data, you're either going to have to create a Singleton Hashtable that stores the data by userId (essentially re-creating Session), or store it in database.